# Disable Insert key on Windows 10 when Scancode Map is already using

Tags: windows-10

I want to disable Insert key on Windows 10 completely. As I know, it is possible if I make registry value `Scancode Map`.

But I already made and use it for changing Caps Lock to second Shift. Is there any way to add additional registry to disable Insert?

Comment: You know that scancode map can handle multiple remaps, right???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use the free key-remapping product
[AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/)
with the following script to disable the <kbd>Insert</kbd> key:

```
$Insert::return
```

AutoHotkey can also handle changing the <kbd>CapsLock</kbd> to <kbd>Shift</kbd>
with no registry changes:

```
SetCapsLockState, AlwaysOff
CapsLock::shift
```

After installing AutoHotKey, put the above text in a `.ahk` file and double-click
it to test. You may stop the script by right-click on the green H icon in the
traybar and choosing Exit. To have it run on login, place it in the Startup group at
`C:\Users\USER-NAME\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup`.